# What is a confidence interval for the ratio of two variables, where the result is greater than or equal to 0, but strictly less than 1?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval

Suppose I have variables $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ and $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$ such that $X_i$ is independent of $X_j$, and that $Y_i$ is independent of $Y_j$ for $i\neq j$. However, it may not be that $X_i$ is independent of $Y_i$. Also, $X_i$ is strictly smaller than $Y_i$. For example, $Y_i$ can be a time variable in seconds, and $X_i$ is a subset of the total time $Y_i$

Suppose I were to define a new variable

$$
Z_i \overset{\Delta}{=} \frac{X_i}{Y_i}
$$

and that $0 \leq Z_i < 1$.

What could be a confidence interval that works for such a setup?

Comment: What if $Y_i=0?$

Comment: @Dave Sorry, I forgot to mention that I have $Y_i$ being strictly positive.

Comment: (1) A confidence interval is a procedure intended to cover a specified *parameter* (that is, distributional property) with a specified frequency.  **What parameter are you estimating??** What are your distributional assumptions? (2) Please explain what it might possibly mean that one random variable is a "subset" of another.  This makes little sense in terms of the usual meanings of "random variable" and "subset."